# Android Gradle Issue - Support Repo Download

Tags: android, gradle

I haven't really done anything as of late to my Android project but, out of nowhere, the gradle won't build in Android Studio:

Sync with Gradle for project 'ClientAndroid' failed: Support repository download failed with code 2

Can't really find any documentation on this issue from anyone else.

Thoughts? Thank you for your time!

Image to gradle:
https://spaces.hightail.com/space/fmxD34zZ86/files/fi-0aec6aa6-5d25-4244-aa55-196f3a6e97bf/fv-03eed1d2-c221-43e6-92da-5317e85c3624/Gradle.docx

Comment: Ideally, now, you are using `compileSdkVersion 26` and are using the `26.0.2` edition of the support libraries. In that case, there is no more support repository on your hard drive. Instead, you use `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`, as outlined in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library). That gets you up to date and should eliminate this error in one step.

Comment: This project is on compileSdkVersion 24 and buildToolsVersion 24.0.0. It's been this way for a while and shouldn't need to change. However, even WITH your suggested changes, I get the same results. :(

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: I updated the original post @GabrieleMariotti Thank you!